# How to modify numpy array with arbitrary indices in vectorized way?

Tags: python, numpy

## Simplified story

Suppose I have an array `arr` and indices `idx`.
For each `i` occuring in `idx`, I want to increase `arr[i]` by one.

A non-vectorized approch will be like this:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros(5)
idx = [0, 1, 1, 2, 0]

for i in idx:
    arr[i] += 1
```

Is there any way to vectorize this?

Note that `arr[idx] += 1` is invalid because of the duplicate indices.

```
arr = np.zeros(1)
idx = [0, 0]
arr[idx] += 1  # arr becomes array([1]), not array([2])
```

Of course, using `np.unique()` can achieve the same goal in this 1D array example. But actually I am trying to deal with 2D array and I doubt that counting the elements would be the best solution.

### Edit

`np.unique` indeed works, but it seems there is unnecessary slowdown. I would like a faster approach (if exists).

Here is an example of 2D indices for 10,000 points without duplicate.

```py
arr = np.zeros((10000, 10000))
idx = np.stack([np.arange(10000), np.arange(10000)])

%timeit np.unique(idx, axis=1, return_counts=True)  # takes 1.93 ms

%timeit arr[idx[0], idx[1]] += 1  # takes 235 μs
```

Apparently, iterating by indexing is ~10 times faster.

### Edit2

@PaulS's answer was faster than `np.unique`.

```py
%timeit np.add.at(arr, (idx[0], idx[1]), 1) # takes 925 μs
```

### Edit3

Here is the example with random index to test duplicate indices.

```py
arr = np.zeros((10000, 10000))
ran = (np.random.rand(10000)*10).astype(int)
idx = np.stack([ran, ran])

%timeit np.unique(idx, axis=1, return_counts=True)  # takes 3.24 ms

%timeit np.add.at(arr, (idx[0], idx[1]), 1) # takes 859 μs
```

(edit: typo)

## Detailed story

I am trying to implement a Hough line transformation algorithm using NumPy. (The reason why I'm not using `cv2.HoughLines()` is because I want the result directly from the coordinates of the points, not from binary array).

Getting the curves in `(r, θ)` plane was easy, but I am having trouble implementing the accumulator in vectorized way. Currently I am relying on flattening the 2D data into 1D. Is there a nicer and faster way to perform accumulation?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1D arrays**

Another possible solution:

```
np.add.at(arr, idx, 1)
```

Output:

```
[2. 2. 1. 0. 0.]
```

---

**2D arrays**

(Thanks, @mozway, for your example, that I am now using here.)

```
arr = np.zeros([3, 4], dtype=int)
idx = [[0, 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 3, 1]]

np.add.at(arr, (idx[0], idx[1]), 1)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm without speed loss.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the unique indices and their count:

```
idx2, cnt = np.unique(idx, return_counts=True)

arr[idx2] += cnt
```

Updates `arr`:

```
array([2, 2, 1, 0, 0])
```

##### with nd-arrays (example in 2D):

```
arr = np.zeros([3, 4], dtype=int)
idx = [[0, 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 3, 1]]

idx2, cnt = np.unique(idx, axis=1, return_counts=True)
arr[*idx2] = cnt
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

If the indices are transposed:

```
arr = np.zeros([3, 4], dtype=int)
idx = idx = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [2, 3], [0, 1]]

idx2, cnt = np.unique(idx, axis=0, return_counts=True)
arr[*idx2.T] = cnt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But as I stated in my question, would there be any other way?

Comment: @JSS why? this works very well with 2D (ND) array (see updated example)

Comment: Also using `arr[idx]` directly would be ambiguous, if you used multiplication and had a duplicated coordinate, would you want to multiply 2 times by 1? or by 2?

Comment: Because `np.unique` seems a little bit slow. Please see my updated question.